# What is a good test case showing the regex performance problems of the pre/post/match vars in Perl?

Tags: regex, performance, perl

In the `English` module and a few other places, users are advised never to use the `$&` `` $` `` and `$'` variables or their `English` equivalents `$MATCH $PREMATCH $POSTMATCH` due to the fact that they will slow down all regex use.

What is a good test case (benchmark) that shows the performance problems?

Comment: A classic Benchmark test won't work here, because as soon as these variables are used anywhere in the interpreter, the penalty is applied universally. You'd have to write up separate scripts and invoke them individually.

Comment: yeah, that was my approach, but in the simple test cases I was trying (long string with an early matching regex) I couldn't see a measurable difference between a run with and without the vars.

Comment: As of 5.10 you should be able to write a single test script using the `/p` modifier as a proxy for triggering the global match vars.

Comment: @Ether: My dumbbench tool can trivially benchmark multiple scripts while attempting to factor out and subtract the startup cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple starting point, looking for a single character in strings of varying lengths. The match variables make copies of the source string so I expected the penalty to be proportional to the amount of copying required. Reality seems to be the opposite. (This is why we benchmark, children.) The cost of matching against a longer string outweighs the overhead of making a copy. In retrospect, that makes sense, as the copy is just a `memcpy` while the regex engine has to scan character-by-character.

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

for my $n (map { 10 ** $_ } 0 .. 4) {
    my $string = 'a' x $n . 0 . 'a' x $n;

    print "N = $n:\n";
    cmpthese(1000000, {
        'w/ match vars'  => sub { $string =~ /\d/p },
        'w/o match vars' => sub { $string =~ /\d/  },
    });
    print "\n";
}
```

Results:

```
N = 1:
            (warning: too few iterations for a reliable count)
                    Rate  w/ match vars w/o match vars
w/ match vars  1184834/s             --           -54%
w/o match vars 2557545/s           116%             --

N = 10:
                    Rate  w/ match vars w/o match vars
w/ match vars  1164144/s             --           -49%
w/o match vars 2283105/s            96%             --

N = 100:
                    Rate  w/ match vars w/o match vars
w/ match vars   865052/s             --           -45%
w/o match vars 1560062/s            80%             --

N = 1000:
                   Rate  w/ match vars w/o match vars
w/ match vars  224568/s             --           -21%
w/o match vars 284333/s            27%             --

N = 10000:
                  Rate  w/ match vars w/o match vars
w/ match vars  26667/s             --           -15%
w/o match vars 31480/s            18%             --
```